# DevExpress' Ribbon bar: how to disable and hide "Full Screen Button"

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, ribbon

Windows 7 SP1 (x86) + Delphi XE2 + DevExpress 2013.1.2 (VCL) + TdxBarManager + skin "Office2013White".

How to disable and hide "Full Screen Button" in design-mode and/or runtime-mode (screenshot of button):

[image]

I tried to find it in resources (*.pas), then tried to edit skin by dxSkinEditor (*.skinres), but failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't that button (action) present in the TdxBarManager? Sometimes when you remove a TdxBarButton from the screen, its entry remains present in the TdxBarManager, and you also have to remove it there. Maybe the skinning code is using that remnant...

Comment: No, there is no this option. I mean there is no this option in list of hints for TdxBarManager and in Object Inspector.

Comment: You can also post at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Comment: I can't - I haven't got a license (using trial demo) so they ignored my question :(

Comment: Is that the default Full Screen button of the form? I assume not, because that has nothing to do woth TDxBarManager. But what kind of a button is it then? Located where? Please edit your question.

Comment: Yep, this button is visible only when a skin "Office2013White" is active. If "Office2010" or "Office2007" skins - then this button is invisible. I just can't find any properties of this button in resources for disable (or hide) it, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RibbonAutoHideMode.Enabled := False;
end;
```